# Python: How to use a dataframe outside the class which is built inside class?

Tags: pandas, class

```
class Builder():
    def __init__(self, args, date, crv)
    def listInstruments(self, crv):
    df_list = pd.DataFrame(columns=['curve','instrument','quote'])
    for instrument, data in self.instruments.items():
        if 'BASIS' in instrument:
            for........
        else:
            for quote in data['QUOTES']:
                new_row = {'curve':crv,'instrument':instrument,'quote':quote}
                df = df_list.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

Above is the code for reference. I would like to use df for further analysis outside this class. How can I print df outside this class ? Please suggest.

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Is everything from `df_list` and below supposed to be the body of `listInstruments()` method? If so, then `df` will only be defined if your else clause executes, and it will be equivalent to the value assigned on the last iteration in which that clause is reached. If you always want to have `df` populated and returned, you'll need to assign it a value in the first if clause as well.